# Should a JSON response return a base64-encoded file?

Tags: .net, json, web-services

I'm creating a web service that will return XPS documents that are "queued" by other users. I'd like to minimize the number of requests, therefore I was thinking of combining the resulting queued files into one response:

```js
"Files":
[
  {"Id": 1, "ContentType": "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument", "Data": "base64-encoded data of file here" },
  {"Id": 2, "ContentType": "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument", "Data": "another files base64 data"}
]
```

Is this a terrible idea? Is there anything I should be concerned about? Because multiple servers will be polling this API, I'd really like to minimize the number of requests sent. If there is a better way to do this, I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

FWIW, the method I was planning to use to base64-encode/decode the files was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/693875/200322).

Comment: I don't generally think that one request per file is too much. What you are doing may work, but seems slightly-overly-complex for the tradeoff.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I agree about the idea of KISS. However, if there are 10 servers hitting this API with 20 files each every couple of minutes, I feel like the number of requests needs to be reduced. Additionally it would mean I'd have to expose another method in the public API.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. If it is performance or throughput, Base64 increases data size by a half. If it's embedding file data into arbitrary structures, the ease of passing them around as-is may outweigh the performance hit.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - Yup I agree, it is a disadvantage to this approach :(. I'm just trying to get thoughts on how to do this sensibly.

Comment: To add more complexity on you, what are your file sizes? Depending on that, it might be necessary to limit the number of files (possibly based on their sizes), so your overall response size isn't ginormous

Comment: @minnow - They're going to be pretty small XPS documents (single-paged). And yes, limiting the number of files in a response was definitely on the list.

Comment: 10 servers making 20 requests each every few minutes? That doesn't seem like much. Any modern server should be able to handle 200 requests a minute with no problem. Unless the requests require some seriously heavy duty processing on the server end.

Comment: @JimMischel - That load was just an example. I'd like this API to scale relatively easily from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip/compress the files into an archive? That avoids the base64 explosion of data.

EDIT: As you also asked in the comments how to handle metadata for each file, let me summarize here for easy future reference:

1. Put the metadata into the comment field of each zip file entry.
2. For each file, create a separate file in the archive with the same name plus some key extension (.metadata?) that you put the metadata into.
3. Embed the metadata into the file name. (I guess this is a new idea)

Comment: Yeah - I actually had this originally, but it didn't easily allow me to provide metadata about the files (id, name, created by etc).

Comment: for each file, create a separate file in the archive with the same name plus some key extension (.metadata?) that you put the metadata into?

Comment: A better idea would be to use the comment field of the zip file for the metadata.

Comment: I'm going to go with my original gut and just zip the files and use either the .metadata suggestion or the comment field. Thanks for this!

Comment: I thought I should make clear that each file in a zip archive has it's own comment field. There isn't one comment field for the entire zip archive as my previous comment could be interpreted to be saying.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the goal, two answers come to my mind:

1) Using a different data format that is easily parseable by client and allows binary data without conversions (some kind of serialization or just a structured preamble before raw file data).

2) Saving the .xps document somewhere (probably ramdisk) and serving it with a separate file request.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is whether request overhead is a significant portion of the bandwidth or time required to fulfill requests for N documents.

That is, it takes some amount of time and bandwidth to serve N documents in N requests (i.e. one document per request).

It likely takes *less* bandwidth to serve N documents in M requests (where M is < N). However, is the bandwidth savings significant? Is there any savings in processing on the server side? There is certainly some per-request overhead, but if the documents are large, the bandwidth difference will be negligible. If the server's per-*document* processing time is significantly larger than the per-request time, then the savings will be negligible.

That said, it's usually a good idea to batch data if you can. I wouldn't say that base64 encoding the JSON is a bad idea. It's an excellent idea if your clients are already set up to work with JSON. You can save on bandwidth, at the cost of some server time, by enabling automatic compression (typically gzip) on the server.