# C# Reading text from file with binary content

Tags: c#, file, pdf, encoding

I want to read a PDF file as a string.
I'm using `File.ReadAllText(path)`, but the result ends on the first stream of binary data.
I think it recognizes some part of the stream as the end of file and stops.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can extract text from a PDF using tools as [IText7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iText7/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base64 Encode a PDF in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475421/base64-encode-a-pdf-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read a PDF file as a string, because a PDF file contains other data than just characters. Read the file into a `byte` array or parse it switching between reading text and binary data whenever you encounter a stream object in the PDF file.

Some languages like PHP treat strings and byte arrays as interchangeable. That is not the case in C#.